# Classification of 20 million records to 200 categories

Tags: classification, natural-language, text-mining, multinomial-distribution, many-categories

I have a data set of 20 million records, which I need to assign to 200 categories.
(Business language - based on the text description, I need to assign it to one of the 200 departments).

Suppose I have to use (multinomial) logistic regression, how can I handle such huge number of target categories? 
To generalise, for any ML classification algorithm, what should be the approach to handle such target variables with a large number of options.

Note : I am using Python + NLP (with an option for deep learning)

Comment: I'd use a random classification forest, and let it tell me how many categories there are.  I would then look at relating those to the departments.

Comment: you need to define features/variables first before running an algorithm, in your example, the features could be the words people used. then you perform some text cleaning. i.e. remove keywords, stemming, lemmatization, tf-idf transformation... Then put these created variables into your multinomial logistic regression .

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I was a bit worried about the no of target variable levels. @EngrStudent : Don't we have to tell the Random Forest about our target variable while training, instead of the model telling us how many categories are there ?

Comment: @Sreenath1986 - You can make it a cousin of an autoeconder.  Run boruta on each of your 200 columns, and it will tell you the one2 that is driven by the most of the others.  You can then select the output columns whose important inputs span the remainder of your space.  Start with them.  It is a poor mans PCA in ML/boruta domain.

Comment: @EngrStudent thaks for the tips. let me try them out